# Django - Leaving socket open while receiving data

Tags: python, django, html, sockets

When I try to load in a largish (50mb) video, the server throws this error:

```
[14/Mar/2016 02:16:13] "GET /media/media/uploads/SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 52464391
[14/Mar/2016 02:16:13] "GET /media/media/uploads/SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 286720
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 328, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
[14/Mar/2016 02:16:13] "GET /media/media/uploads/SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 52070)
```

As you can see the video is requested twice before the error is thrown. It seems this is caused when the socket closes before the whole video is loaded in. This is also supported by the fact small videos don't throw errors (on Chrome - everything throws an error on Safari)

I'm using django 1.9 in the development server and html5 to display the videos onto the page.

How would I be able to keep the socket open until all the packets have been received? And why would this even be the default behaviour? I can't think of any useful application of having the socket close before all the required data is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AWS S3 to store and handle the media this problem was fixed on all browsers. It must have something to do with the development server.